# Terminology: Xth element of array vs element at index X

Tags: java, arrays, terminology

I have been self taught for awhile, but I've finally got the chance to attend a genuine Comp Sci class this semester.
Today, we had a question that asked what subscripting an array with 100 does:

```
pixelArray[100]
```

All of the answers that sounded right, however, said that the loc above accessed "the 100th pixel in the array". I was sure this was a trick question, because pixelArray[100] would be the 101st pixel. But no. (I also accidentally said 99 instead of 101 and got treated to the whole 'arrays count from zero' spiel)

I always thought it was something like this:

```
var foo = arbitraryArray[5];
/* 
foo is the sixth element of the array
foo is the element at index 5
*/
```

But the way that the teacher described it, arbitraryArray[5] is the fifth element of the array.

I'm not looking to prove my teacher wrong, I'm sure she is at least mostly right. The only question I have is, am I crazy or does the phrasing "Xth element" imply counting from 1?

Comment: Your instructor may have simply misspoke, as it is quite easy to mix up index (or offset) counting with ordinal counting. The technical terms for these methods of counting can help in a discussion… An [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics)) is the position of an element within a sequence (first, second, …) versus [zero-based numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) for an index/offset.

Answer (score 4):

Your teacher is wrong.

`array[5]` is the *sixth* element of the array.

Reasons why this is so:

- Java arrays are zero-based, so array[0] is the first element
- The array needs a size of (at least) 6 to address the element at index 5
- There are 5 elements before the element at index 5, namely those at 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4

There are languages that use one-based arrays (but none worth knowing about)

Comment: At least I know I'm not alone. Like I said, I'm not gonna go correct her… it might be a simplification because this is the first course they offer that isn't, like, Alice or some pseudo language like that.